# Incomplete feed dictionary for graph consisting of multiple separate parts?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I read somewhere around here that running multiple Tensorflow graphs in a single process is considered bad practice. Therefore, I now have a single graph which consists of multiple separate "sub-graphs" of the same structure. Their purpose is to generate specific models that describe production tolerances of multiple sensors of the same type. The tolerances are different for each sensor.

I'm trying to use TF to optimize a loss function in order to come up with a numerical description (i.e. a tensor) of that production tolerance for each sensor separately.

In order to achieve that and avoid having to deal with multiple graphs (i.e. avoid *bad practice*), I built a graph that contains a distinct sub-graph for each sensor.

The problem is that I only get data from a single sensor at a time. So, I cannot build a `feed_dict` that has all `placeholders` for all sub-graphs filled with numbers (all zeros wouldn't make sense).

TF now complains about missing values for certain placeholders, namely those of the other sensors that I don't have yet. So basically I would like to calculate a sub-graph without feeding the other sub-graphs.

Is that at all possible and, if yes, what will I have to do in order to hand an incomplete feed_dict to the graph?

If it's not possible to train only parts of a graph, even if they have no connection to other parts, what's the royal road to create models with the same structure but different weights that can get trained separately but don't use multiple graphs?

Comment: Why wouldn't all zeros make sense? If you only need Sensor A data to execute the computation of Sensor A's part of the graph (and the part of the loss related to Sensor A), then the calculations and the loss of other parts of the graph could be garbage noise and it won't matter. Then, in the output, only the particular tolerance for Sensor A would be meaningful (maybe it's the first entry of the output tensor?) while the other outputs can (and should) just be garbage. Basically, your overall graph will have three inputs, only one of which needs to be "real" for any given computation.

Comment: Are you making a network or some other topology in which Sensor A's tolerance level ultimately has connections to nodes of the graph that depend on Sensor B's data? If yes, then you *do* need all sensor data, and you simply cannot execute the graph until all required sensor data is available (so maybe you wait and batch up your calls to run the model?). If no, then you don't need other sensor data and you can execute with garbage data for the other inputs. Although, at that point, why not just write functions that wrap a common graph, and only take one input?

Comment: There are no connections between the graphs of the sensors. All I do is optimize the matrix that moves the sensor output closer to the ground truth. They are all completely separate from each other. I understand that all zeros doesn't make sense because it would be used by the graph as a valid sample, i.e. actually be used for training of the other sensor's models, and interfere with what they've "learned" so far. Furthermore my loss function contains a cosine_distance which requires normalized vectors as input. It's simply impossible to calculate the cosine distance between to null-vectors.

Comment: Ah, wait... since there's no connection between the sub-graphs and I only run a loss function which interacts with the particular sub-graph, it should not alter the other graphs' knowledge, is that right? In that case, all zeros would indeed work. I'll try that.

Comment: If you need to be extra careful, you can also use `tf.case` in the loss function, and choose which subset of loss terms matter based on which input(s) was actually provided, and set all other loss components to zero.

Comment: Okay, but how do I sort of "fill" the irrelevant feed_dict elements with zeros? I guess, I'll need to know the placeholders of the other sensors for this but each sensor is encapsulated in a class instance. The instances of that class only share the TF graph and the session. They don't know about each other and thus about the other elements for the feed_dict.